# Certain elements in uniform array incorrectly being optimized out?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opentk, lighting, uniform

I'm beginning to create a basic diffuse lighting shader, I'm using uniforms arrays to store the lights' infos.

The loops are of variable size dictated by the "DirectionLightsLength" uniform. For some reason, all elements asides from the zeroeth is being optimized out of my code (OpenGL can't find it's location). Is there anyway to prevent this without manually unrolling my for-loops and removing their variable length?

I'm setting up the arrays on the shader end by setting the uniform location of "shaderName[index]",

```
uniform vec3 DirectionLightsDirections[4];
uniform vec3 DirectionLightsColors[4];
uniform int  DirectionLightsLength;

out vec2 v2f_uv;
out vec3 v2f_diffuse;
out vec3 v2f_normal_world;

uniform mat4 ModelRotation;
uniform mat4 ModelToWorld;
uniform mat4 WorldToView;


void main()
{
    vec4 worldPos =  vec4(in_position, 1f) * ModelToWorld;
    vec4 viewPos =   worldPos * WorldToView;

    gl_Position = viewPos;
    v2f_uv = in_uv;

    v2f_normal_world = (vec4(in_normal, 1f) * ModelRotation).xyz;
    
    vec3 diffuseColorSum = vec3(0,0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < DirectionLightsLength; i++){
        float product = dot(DirectionLightsDirections[i], v2f_normal_world);
        float diffuseShade = clamp(product, 0, 1);
        vec3 diffuseColor = product * DirectionLightsColors[i];
        diffuseColorSum += diffuseColor;
    }
    v2f_diffuse = clamp(diffuseColorSum, 0, 1);
}
```

Thanks for any help!
I'm using OpenTK, a c# wrapper for OpenGL.

Comment: I actually already have tried that, for some reason it still doesn't work... that's why I'm not 100% sure if it's actually optimizing the elements out... but I've checked my code which sends the uniform data to shader 20+ times. :/

Comment: That doesn't work either... so it must be the way I'm assigning uniform values? I'm guessing that OpenTK might not be a perfect wrapper and handles assignment uniform arrays slightly different so the glfw tutorials I'm using don't translate exactly. I'm going to try assignment uniform arrays in a different way and see if that works.

Comment: *"I'm guessing that OpenTK might not be [...]"* - No. The OpenGL API is implemented by the graphics driver. OpenTK just delegates to the API functions which are provided by the graphics driver.

Comment: That didn't work either, now I'm pretty sure it's because I cache all the locations of my uniforms in a dictionary[string, int] per material for performance reasons. But when I call  `GL.GetProgram(Shader.Handle, GetProgramParameterName.ActiveUniforms, out int uniformCount);` and then cycle through the uniforms with`GL.GetActiveUniform(Shader.Handle, i, out _, out var type);` there aren't any uniforms of array type that are found...

Comment: your code doesn't make sense, `diffuseColorSum` is never declared. also, the fragment shader is missing. Optimization works on the _whole program_. I'd also avoid the double declaration of `i`.

Comment: Sorry about the non-compileable code, i was in the middle of taking out variables and putting them back in for debugging purposes. My actually shader code (now revised) DOES compile, just the non [0] elements location's are not found and their values default to all zeros. I changed the method I used to send uniforms to my shader, nothing has worked thus far. Only the first element of any of my arrays are actually considered an activeUniform. I'm using OpenGL4 if that makes a difference... (also I have the fragment shader in a seperate text file which I can post)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: if I declare my light uniforms inside a single struct in the shader like this

```
struct DirectionLight{
    vec3 Color;
//... other members
};

uniform DirectionLight directionLights [4];
```

They are then counted as active uniforms when I cache all uniform locations of a material, and I can therefore access their locations via a string-key (I cache uniform locations in a c# dictionary) which follows the following format:
`$"{light_name}[{index}]{member_name}"`

I don't know if this means OpenTK doesn't support raw uniform arrays that *aren't structs*, but this  is the only thing I've found works. I was going to eventually refactor all my uniforms into structs anyways so I guess this is fine.

Thanks for the help everybody, and my bad for a sloppy question!